# Django throwing error 404 while connecting with stripe webhook

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Hey guys I am keep getting 404 error on while using Stripe webhook in my Django app. Really appreciate your help

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('my_webhook/', views.my_webhook, name='my_webhook')]
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
            json.loads(payload), stripe.api_key
        )
    
    except:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    
    if event.type == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        payment_intent = event.data.object
    elif event.type == 'payment_method.attached':
        payment_method = event.data.object
    else:
        print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event.type))
    
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Error:

```
[20/Jul/2021 14:28:36] "POST /my_webhook HTTP/1.1" 404 3816
Not Found: /my_webhook
```

Localhost details:

stripe listen --forward-to
localhost:8000/stripe/my_webhook/

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` to display error to check if this is the problem - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`. And if this makes problem then you should use `print(payload, stripe.api_key)` to check if you use correct values. But you use `status=400` and error shows `404` so problem can be in different place. Did you try to run it without code in `my_webhook` - only return reponse?

Comment: I m using localhost 8000....

Comment: you could add all details in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: You might want to checkout the setting for [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#append-slash), seems like you are getting 404 for `/my_webhook` but the path you registered is `/my_webhook/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comments guys.

I found the solution. While calling `stripe listen` I also need to mention my app name.

Previously in stripe CLI I was using

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/my_webhook/
```

then I added my app name in it and it started working

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/pred/my_webhook/
```

where "pred" is the name of my app